# Using a function to create an instance of a class based on the type passed through

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
internal static void AssignNewArrayItem(ref Xml.CLASSNAME[] Items, Xml.CLASSNAME Item)
{
    if (Items != null)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref Items, Items.Length + 1);
        Items[Items.Length - 1] = Item;
    }
    else
        Items = new Xml.CLASSNAME[] { Item };
}
```

At the moment I have about 10 overloaded versions where `CLASSNAME` is different but they all do the exact same thing. Is there any way I can have `CLASSNAME` as a generic object and cast the vars to achieve the same result?

I am open to other suggestions to acheive the same result if I am going about this in the wrong way as well.

Comment: I am not sure of the rest of your architecture, but is there any reason you aren't using a [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). It grows dynamically for you without the need for the array resizing that you are doing.

Comment: More specifically a List will only resize the underlying array occasionally, so that most operations don't involve a resize, as opposed to resizing it every single time.  It keeps track of which elements in the underlying array are actually 'valid' so that things like Count still work as you would want.

Comment: The Arrays are in a XML Mapping file generated using xsd.exe so I don't think there is a way to use a List<> in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
internal static void AssignNewArrayItem<T>(ref T[] Items, T Item)
    {
        if (Items != null)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref Items, Items.Length + 1);
            Items[Items.Length - 1] = Item;
        }
        else
            Items = new T[] { Item };
    }
```

Comment: glad to help. But as others mentioned, you may use List<T> or an arraylist instead of array of T in order not to do anything related with array resizing

Comment: The Arrays are in a XML Mapping file generated using xsd.exe so I don't think there is a way to use a List<> in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
internal static void AssignNewArrayItem<T>(ref T[] Items, T Item)
{
    if (Items != null)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref Items, Items.Length + 1);
        Items[Items.Length - 1] = Item;
    }
    else
        Items = new T[] { Item };
}
```

I think using a `List<T>` would be the better option here though.

Comment: +1 for suggesting List<T>. This resizing could get real expensive if adding more than a couple elements to it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work. As you suggested yourself, just use generics. To get this in your method, you simply change anywhere there is going to be a variable type with the value between the brackets (it does not have to be T, but that is the convention)

```
internal static void AssignNewArrayItem<T>(ref T[] Items, T Item)
{
    if (Items != null)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref Items, Items.Length + 1);
        Items[Items.Length - 1] = Item;
    }
    else
        Items = new T { Item };
}
```

You should possibly put [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the method, though. Do you have a base type you are expecting? If so, you could do this:

```
internal static void AssignNewArrayItem<T>(ref T[] Items, T Item) 
    where T : <base class name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic constraints, the constraint will only accept objects that inherit from the class `Xml.CLASSNAME`

```
internal static void AssignNewArrayItem<T>(ref T[] Items, T Item) where T: Xml.CLASSNAME
{
    if (Items != null)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref Items, Items.Length + 1);
        Items[Items.Length - 1] = Item;
    }
    else
        Items = new Xml.CLASSNAME[] { Item };
}
```